# is there a way you can move elements from one vector and move it to another?

Tags: c++

I would like to know how I can move elements from one vector to another like for example deck vector has ace, hearts, spades. Can I move hearts from the deck vector to the player vector. I doing c++ programming.

```
vector <string> deck {"ace", "spade", "hearts"};
vector <string> player1 {};
```

Comment: `player1 = deck`? What have you tried? What should the result be?

Comment: @KamilCuk he asked for a `move` not a `copy`

Comment: @KamilCuk OP asked to "move hearts". I suppose that indicates moving not all the `deck` contents.

Comment: Something like `player1.push_back(std::move(deck[2]));`, plus `deck.resize(2);`? Note that due to _small string optimization_ (provided by all major implementations), move will likely not be faster than copy.

Comment: the result should be for example moving hearts to player 1 vector. The outcome should update the vector and show that player 1 has hearts. It's not copy, it's move, I haven't tried anything yet due to not knowing what to exactly do.

Comment: @DanielLangr thanks I used what you said it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the **swap()** function.
Something like this should work:

```
deck.swap(player1)
```

Hope it works!